# Implement Date Picker inside layout not as dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, datepicker

I need date picker inside layout not as Dialog. I searched but getting only about dialog. Is there any way to implement date picker in layout design ?

Comment: have you try any things from your end ?

Comment: I did search but can't able to found.

Comment: Try from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301641/android-date-picker-using-xml-layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:endYear="2100"
        android:startYear="1900"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it's come with calendar I want only day / month / year

Comment: Glad to help you... can you please approve and upvote this ans so it may help other user ?